# Messenger Connect OAuth Wrap api to get user emails

Tags: php, oauth, windows-live-id

I want to write a php script using which i can import the address book of a user from hotmail/windows live. I am using Messenger Connect OAuth Wrap api to do that. After getting the access token, i retrieved user's contacts using http://apis.live.net/V4.1/cid-'.$uid.'/Contacts/AllContacts .. though it returns email hashes instead of email addresses. I have looked all over the documentation.. it says that using the above call it will return email hashes instead of addresses. And there is no other method mentioned there to get actual email address. Can someone please guide me in this regard?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can only get the hashes, not the actual email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old post but i got the solution of your problem .

I have faced same situation in the my project too.

The solution is extend the scope of your retrieving data.

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={APPID}&`scope=wl.signin%20wl.basic%20wl.emails%20wl.contacts_emails&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://{REDIRECT_URI}`
```

Then you will get actual email.

Hope this helps someone else. :)